# Can you do this is PHP? With arrays and if statements

Tags: php

Just wondering how you can make this possible in PHP if you can or there is a better way it would be great.

With arrays and if statements

```
<?php
$products = array(
    0 => array(
        "product_name" => "Necklace",
        "product_price" => 10,
        "quantity" => 2,
        "handmade" => "true"
    ),
    array(
        "product_name" => "Bracelet",
        "product_price" => 17,
        "quantity" => 1,
        "handmade" => "false"
    ),
    array(
        "product_name" => "Handthingy",
        "product_price" => 6,
        "quantity" => 3,
        "handmade" => "true"
    )
);
<?php echo $product['handmade']; if('handmade'== true){
    //Do this
} else {
    //Do this
}
```

Comment: And what do you want to do?

Comment: Make what possible? What is it you are trying to do and how is it not working?

Comment: I wasent sure it is a 'legal' statement you can do in PHP

Comment: `array=[] ` isn't a legal statement; perhaps you meant `foreach($products as $product) {`

Comment: I wasent sure if it was possible in PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry that was a mistake

Comment: @Shaun'Prawn185Moore: Well, writing syntactically invalid PHP code isn't possible in PHP.  But writing code which *does something* is possible.  The question is, what are you trying to *do*?

Comment: In the array when handmade = true do one thing, if it = false do 'else'

Comment: And as your values for `handmade` are all strings in the array, comparing a string `"handmade"` with a Boolean `true` (`if('handmade'== true){`) isn't a good comparison, because it will always be false

Comment: Shaun 'Prawn185 Moore, you might want to determine if you need a string or a Boolean for those true/false values.  Generally Boolean is better.  See note by @AbraCadaver below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the foreach loop:

```
foreach($products as $product){
    if($product['handmade'] === 'true'){
       //do this
    }
    else {
       //do that
    }
}
```

This will iterate through the items in the product array, and check each one to see if it is handmade.  If this is not what you are trying to do, give more information.

Comment: Just tried it and it worked thanks! (Im really new to PHP )

Comment: Careful, those are strings so compare to string 'true' instead. `var_dump('false' == true) = true` and `var_dump('true' === true) = false`

Comment: Good point, @AbraCadaver, I just updated my answer to reflect this.  I failed to see it in the original question.